Geforce RTX 3060 driver for Ubuntu 23.04, driver not found
Geforce RTX 3060 driver for Ubuntu 23.04 is not found, when we run the command "nvidia-smi" it shows "Driver were not found" but earlier it was working properly, randomly it stopped working and stopped showing the graphic card on the terminal with the command 'nvidia-smi' ,
What should i do now??

Ubuntu 23.04 (along with all flavors) is End-of-Life and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/01/26/ubuntu-23-04-lunar-lobster-reached-end-of-life-on-january-25-2024/   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades
